# Regex to split numbers from letters

Tags: php, regex

I want to split number and letters from string but have problem .
**Inputs like:**
input example 1 : `A5`
input example 2 : `C16`
input example 3 : `A725`
input example 4 : `X05`
**Result must be:**
Result example 1 :`'A','5'`
Result example 2 : `'C','16'`
Result example 3 : `'A','725'`
Result example 4 : `'X','05'`

I try to it with belo regex but don't give a good result :
`preg_split('/(?=\d+)/', $input)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to add a negative look-behind to make sure the empty string that is chosen is not somewhere in the middle of two digits.

Currently for string `A725`, your regex will split on the empty string before `7`, `2` and `5`, as all of them are followed by at least one digit.

You can use this regex:

```
preg_split('/(?<!\d)(?=\d+)/', $input)
```

Comment: Cool , thanks Rohit jain . no any say more need , It's right ;)

Comment: you answered it very fast and I must wait for a long time to accept it , 15 minutes! :)

Comment: @root Yeah I know that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$s = 'A5,C16,A725,X05';
if (preg_match_all("~(?>[a-z]+|\d+)~i", $s, $arr))
   var_dump($arr[0]);
```

gives:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "16"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "725"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "X"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "05"
}
```

Comment: thanks anubhava , I accept below answer , I now edit question to better information of inputs and results , thanks too ;).